# Spring Initializr - LSP - Failed to fetch Generation from Spring IO: port out of range: -1

Tags: spring-boot

I wanted to learn to make REST services, so I was suggested to use Spring Boot.
I created a new project in Eclipse, using the Spring Boot Initializr plugin.
The dependencies included are: Spring Web, Spring Data JPA, and H2 Database.

After I confirmed the creation of the new project, and Maven downloaded all of the dependencies, this error came up:
[image: screenshot]

How can I solve this? Is this crucial to get the project working?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a small error in this version of Eclipse (I use STS 4.20.1).

It is related to the default proxy settings: Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections. By default, it is configured with 'Native.' If you change it to 'Direct,' the annoying message stops appearing.

I don't use a proxy, so I can leave it like that. If you have a proxy defined in Windows, you should copy the configuration to Eclipse when setting it to 'Direct.'

Comment: The LSP error-message stopped popping up after making this suggested change with Eclipse version 2023-06 (4.28.0) without a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It is a failure caused by not having an explicit port in the application.properties file.

Indicate a port in that file.
For example,

```
server.port = 8081
```

Comment: I thought this worked, but apparently not for me. The Network Connections set to Direct did do the trick for me